# replace source files in html with minified version

Tags: javascript, css, maven

I have successfully created a minified / compressed version of my css and javascript files using a maven plugin

But now i want to replace the section of my main html page that loads all those files, i mean i have this in my html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/app/01.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/app/02.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/app/03.css">
```

that i need to replace with something like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/app/minified.css">
```

and in the javascript section i have this

```
<script src="scripts/01.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/02.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/03.js"></script>
```

that i need to replace with

```
<script src="scripts/minified.js"></script>
```

is there any way to do that with maven ? or do i need something else ?

Answer (score 0):

i have found some success with the com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin. Here is what i have acomplished so far

first i surrounded my styles and scripts with "markers"

```
<!-- replaceCSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/app/01.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/app/02.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/app/03.css">
<!-- replaceCSSEnd -->
...
...
...
<!-- replaceJS -->
<script src="scripts/01.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/02.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/03.js"></script>
<!-- replaceJS -->
```

and in my pom i have included the plugin

```
<plugin>
                    <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>replace</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <file>target/${project.build.finalName}/app/index.html</file>
                        <replacements>
                            <replacement>
                                <token>(?m)&lt;!-- replaceCSS(.|\s)*?replaceCSSEnd --&gt;</token>
                                <value>&lt;link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/styles.css"/&gt;</value>
                            </replacement>
                            <replacement>
                                <token>(?m)&lt;!-- replaceJS(.|\s)*?replaceJSEnd --&gt;</token>
                                <value>&lt;script src="scripts/scripts.js"/&gt;</value>
                            </replacement>
                        </replacements>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

when i run the build, or test the replace with mvn replacer:replace i get an exception that says something like

```
 at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4568)
```

but it only happens when i have both replacement tags, if i leave just the one for the css files, it works fine, the replace is made correctly

another thing is that the replacement is taking place AFTER the war is packaged, wich is obviously wrong